# useState Hook inside loop or conditional statement

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I was reading the updated react docs whose link is [here](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn#using-hooks) there is statement related to `useState`

> If you want to useState in a condition or a loop, extract a new
> component and put it there.

But what I know by the rules of hooks is that you cannot use hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions which is mentioned in the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

So can someone give an example of the first sentence, because they didn't gave an example or there.

My question is can we call hooks inside loops and conditional statements ?

Comment: The initialization of hooks cannot be done in a loop. However, once you have set up a hook, you of course can use it inside a loop.

Answer (score 5):

What they are saying is that if you want to have something with state in loop component:

```
const App = ()=>{
const fields = [someArray]
return(
<div>{fields.map((field)=>{
              const [value, setValue] = useState() //wrong usage!
              return (<input 
                       onChange={(e)=>setValue(e)} 
                       value={value} 
                     />)})})
               
</div>
)}
```

You need to specify component that you wanna loop in new Component and use hook there:

```
const Input = ()=>{
 const [value, setValue]= useState()
 return <input 
             onChange={(e)=>setValue(e)} 
             value={value} 
      />
}
```

and use it in loop

```
const App = ()=>{
 const fiels = [someArray];
 return (
  fields.map((field)=>
   <Input />
   )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Input = ()=>{
 const [value, setValue]= useState()
 return <input 
             onChange={(e)=>setValue(e)} 
             value={value} */ Don't mutate state /*
      />
}
```

We should not be mutating state. React needs to compare it's virtual DOM to the current DOM to determine what to re-render. Futhermore, react hooks are asynchronous, meaning that value may not be updated to e at the point you try and assign to value. This was already achieved with setValue(e).